# Move element out of div using css

Tags: html, css

Effectively, I'm trying to move/position the inner paragraph element (`p`) from within the `.box` div (blue box) to be positioned above the `.box` div (blue box) in the fiddle below:

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
}

.box {
  height: 200px;
  width: 400px;
  background: aqua;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h4>Box heading</h4>
  <div class="box">
    <div class="contents">
      <p>This is some awesome text, which is inside the box</p>
      <p>This is also another great paragraph that is better than any book ever written</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**My expected output is:**

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.box {
  height: 200px;
  width: 400px;
  background: aqua;
  color: black;
}

.contents {
  position: relative;
  top: -50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h4>Box heading</h4>
  <p>This is some awesome text, which is inside the box</p>
  <p>This is also another great paragraph that is better than any book ever written</p>
  <div class="box">
    <div class="contents"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

However, in the above snippet, I have physically placed the paragraph elements above the blue box (`.box` div). Is there a way to essentially move the paragraph element from within the blue box above it using css.

I've tried using `position` attribute or giving the `.contents` a negative margin, however, this doesn't add space for the text to go above and causes overlapping issue with the heading and/or the blue box.

**Note:** The paragraphs within the box can be of any length, so I don't know the height and thus the offset needed for the paragraph.

Comment: Why can't you just move the elements?

Comment: @itodd because I want to move it for a mobile view. On desktop the paragraphs are located within the box.

Comment: Ah ok, check out my answer below - it will grow based on any amount of content

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can consider `position:relative` for the content element and its container and use the same amount of pixel:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.box {
  height: 200px;
  width: 400px;
  background: aqua;
  color: black;
  position: relative;
  top: 110px;
}

.contents {
  position: relative;
  top: -110px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h4>Box heading</h4>
  <div class="box">
    <div class="contents">
      <p>This is some awesome text, which is inside the box</p>
      <p>This is also another great paragraph that is better than any book ever written</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Or consider translate for a more dynamic way:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.box {
  height: 200px;
  width: 400px;
  background: aqua;
  color: black;
  transform:translateY(40%); /*use 100% if height auto*/
}

.contents {
  transform:translateY(-100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h4>Box heading</h4>
  <div class="box">
    <div class="contents">
      <p>This is some awesome text, which is inside the box</p>
      <p>This is also another great paragraph that is better than any book ever written</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems to do the trick. Would there be a way to do this so that if I didn't know the height of the text it could automatically calculate the offset height needed (instead of hard coding `top: -110px`)

Comment: @NickParsons added another way

Comment: @NickParsons oh, I have answered all your CSS questions :p

Answer (score 1):

You could remove the styles from `.box` on mobile and add them to `.content::after`. This will allow for any amount of content in the paragraphs and grow accordingly.

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
}

.box,
.contents::after {
  height: 200px;
  width: 400px;
  background: aqua;
  color: black;
}


/* Mobile only styles */
.box {
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
  background: none;
}

.contents::after {     
  content: ''; 
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h4>Box heading</h4>
  <div class="box">
    <div class="contents">
      <p>This is some awesome text, which is inside the box</p>
      <p>This is also another great paragraph that is better than any book ever written</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```